# Proving a result with limit inf

Tags: analysis, limsup-and-liminf

If a function $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is continuous in $x$, $f$ is sequentially continuous in $x$: $$ \lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} x_n = x \Rightarrow \lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} f(x_n)=f(x)$$

I guess it is not possible in general if one consider $\liminf$ or $\limsup$ instead of $\lim$
$$ \liminf_{n\rightarrow +\infty} x_n = x \Rightarrow \liminf_{n\rightarrow +\infty} f(x_n)=f(x)$$

Also, I guess that if $f$ is also monotone increasing, in addition to continuous, then the result is true with $\liminf$ or $\limsup$. However, I am not able to prove this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that $$\liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty} x_n = x$$
iff for all $\varepsilon>0$, all but finitely many terms of the sequence are more than $x-\varepsilon$ and infinitely many terms are less than $x+\varepsilon$.

Now, if $f$ is an increasing continuous function, fix $\varepsilon>0$. By continuity of $f$,

$$\exists\delta>0:|x-x_n|<\delta\implies|f(x)-f(x_n)|<\varepsilon$$

Consider the sequence $\{f(x_i)\}_{i\in\mathbb N}$. Suppose that infinitely many terms of this sequence are less than $f(x)-\varepsilon$. Then infinitely many terms of original sequence are less than $x-\delta$, which is a contradiction. Similarly, if only finitely many terms of this sequence are less than $f(x)+\varepsilon$, that means all but finitely many terms of this sequence are more than $f(x)+\varepsilon$, which in turn implies that all but finitely many terms of the original sequence are more than $x+\delta$, which is a contradiction again.

Similarly you can prove the limsup part.

**EDIT**

If $f$ is decreasing, then $-f$ is increasing. Hence, liminf of $\{-f(x_i)\}_{i\in\mathbb N}$ is $-f(x)$. Now, we know that on multiplication by $-1$, image of limsup becomes liminf and vice versa. Hence, limsup of $\{f(x_i)\}_{i\in\mathbb N}$ is $f(x)$. Similarly, you can do for limsup of the sequence.

Hope it helps:)

Comment: What happen if the function is decreasing.

Comment: Then image of limsup of sequence will become the liminf of image of the sequence and vice versa.

Comment: Can you write this by mathematical notations in the answer.

Comment: @Helena, I have proved it using the result we have already proven, check the updated answer.

Comment: But still we need compactivity of the domain of the function $f$..

Comment: I found this link: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1812486/prove-lim-sup-f-x-n-f-lim-sup-x-n-and-same-for-inf?rq=1

Comment: @Helena, but if the domain of the function contains an open set containing the given sequence and its limsup and liminf, that will do. Compactness is used to ensure that only in this link.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Attempt:

Let $x_n$ be a bounded sequence.

Want to show that if $f$ is increasing, continuous  then

$\liminf \limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n =L$ implies $\liminf \limits _{n \rightarrow \infty} f(x_n)=f(L)$.

Recall: $L:=\liminf \limits _{n \rightarrow \infty} (x_n)$ is a limit point of $(x_n)$, and

$L= \inf ${$H| H$ limit point of $(x_n)$}.

There exists a subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ with

$\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}x_{n_k} =L$;

$\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} f(x_{n_k})=f(L)$;

$f(L)$ is a limit point of $f(x_n)$.

Need to show that $f(L) =\liminf \limits _{n \rightarrow \infty }f(x_n)$.

Assume $D$ is a limit point of $f(x_n)$; there exists a subsequence $f(x_{n_l})$ with

$\lim_{l \rightarrow \infty}f(x_{n_l})=D$;

$x_{n_l}$ is bounded, since $x_n$ is bounded (assumption).

Bolzano Weierstrass:

There exists a convergent subsequence $b_s$ of $x_{n_l}$ with limit $M$.

$M$ is a limit point of $x_n$ and

$L \le M$.

Continuity:

$\lim_{s \rightarrow \infty} f(b_s)=f(M)=$

$\lim_{l \rightarrow \infty}f(x_{n_l})=D$;

Since $f$ is increasing:

$f(L)\le f(M)=D$, i e.

$f(L)= \liminf \limits _{ n \rightarrow \infty} f(x_n)$.